# bash behaviour of pressing <tab> twice for filename completion

Tags: bash, powershell, tab-completion

As an example, say that I type part of a name:

```
$ vi partn                         <= here I press <tab><tab>
partname     partnook     partnum  <= these are the results
```

This is standard behaviour in `bash` and that is fine, but I've been working a lot on PowerShell lately where the default behaviour is that if you press tab, it cycles through the names, completing each name and then pressing tab again will go to the next file, so if I pressed tab one time, I see `vi ./partname`, then press tab again, I see `vi ./partnook`, then tab again I see `vi ./partnum`. I tend to prefer this behaviour as it's less typing (you just hit tab to cycle through until you get the filename or command that you want).

Everything is customisable in Linux of course, so can someone advise how I might change the default `bash` behaviour to follow the above by default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To persistently **make tab-completion *not* require *two* <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypresses** whenever there are multiple matching completions and to instead ***cycle* through them, *in-line***:

**Option A:** If you either already have:

- an `/etc/inputrc` file (applies system-wide, modification requires `sudo`)
- and/or a `~/.inputrc` file (user-specific)

and/or

you're planning to customize the Readline library extensively and/or want to make customizations effective for *scripts* too when they call `read -e`:

Add line:

```
"\C-i": menu-complete
```

to *either* file, depending on whether you want the setting to be effective for *all* users or the *current* user (create the file, if necessary).

Note: **Alternatively**, you can simply turn off the need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> *twice* and **exhibit the standard behavior *instantly***, which means showing a **multi-column *list* of all possible completions**, and then ***redisplaying* the input line, to allow you to type additional characters** to either fully complete the argument or to type enough of it so that the next <kbd>Tab</kbd> keypress unambiguously completes:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

---

**Option B:** Alternatively, you may add Readline commands to your user-specific initialization file (`~/.bash_profile` on macOS, `~/.bashrc` on Linux and other Unix-like platforms), by passing them as a *single* argument to the [`bind` builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#Bash-Builtins):

```
bind '"\C-i": menu-complete'
```

If you prefer the show-all-matches behavior:

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
```

Note that `bind` commands in `~/.bash_profile` / `~/.bashrc` take precedence over equivalent commands in either `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc`.

As implied above, configuring Readline this way will *not* take effect in *scripts* that call `read -e` in order to activate Readline support for reading user input.

Comment: ok, tried it, and ... it works! Amazing. Thanks Mike, dunno how you always know this stuff, this is great! I used to love how Linux did tab completion (it was massively superior to the bad old DOS days), but then PowerShell's default was just better again than the bash default (in my opinion). Really nice to be able to use this at the bash console. 

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @YorSubs (as an aside: not a big deal, but I go by Michael). Yes, PowerShell's tab completion is very powerful with native PowerShell commands. Making it work with external programs requires additional work, but there are third-party projects that can help - see the [posh-cli module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-cli/) (repository is [here](https://github.com/bergmeister/posh-cli)).